# How to select nearest previous or next div?

Tags: jquery

I may have the following html structure...

```
<p class="one active"></p><!---get this one--->
<p class="bg bg1"></p><!--from here ^^^---->

<p class="two active"></p><!---get this one--->
<p class="bg bg2"></p><!--from here ^^^---->
```

Or like this...

```
<p class="bg bg1"></p><!--from here vvv---->
<p class="one active"></p><!---get this one--->


<p class="bg bg2"></p><!--from here vvv---->
<p class="two active"></p><!---get this one--->
```

Now I want to find the nearest previous or next p from bg.

For first case I do:

```
$(this).prev('.active')
```

For second case I do:

```
$(this).next('.active')
```

---

**Update Note:** I think my question is missunderstood:

I need to do by checking html structure... if active classes are previous then select previous else next...

And you could see the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V5HJ6/). I'm taking the @Barmar's example

for first case: active classes are in previous order and for second case: active classes are in next order....

So, for first case: it should select previous and for second case: it should select next.

Comment: `'active'` should be `'.active'`

Comment: You could write your own custom selector if there isn't one already.

Comment: none of the answers working correctly, please review my edit comments...

Comment: Update hasn't clarified it. In your fiddle, when you click on `bg2`, both `one` and `two` are the same distance, and they're both active. Why should it select `two` instead of `one`?

Comment: for second case: check first bg has no prev active class.. clear??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional operator:

```
$(this).prev('.active').length ? $(this).prev('.active') : $(this).next('.active')
```

Comment: This selects prev if it exists, else next, not by any distance. (the question is a bit vague on what does "closest/nearest" mean here).

Comment: From his examples, it looks like it's always before or after, he just doesn't know which it will be in a particular case.

Comment: Also, better not execute the class selector twice though, so the if statement would be better.

Comment: suppose, for second case if you target nearest active class from bg2 then it will select both prev and next active classes but that's not what I want...

Comment: This returns one or the other, never both

Comment: If both the previous and next element are active, how is it supposed to decide which one to select?

Comment: checking html structure... if active classes are previous then select previous else next...

Comment: That's what I do. When you click on `bg2`, the active element is the previous one, so I select that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select both of them, then you could do:

```
$(this).prev('.active').add($(this).next('.active'))
```

Comment: You are missing the `length` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method:

```
$.fn.nearest = function(selector) {
    return this.next().add(this.prev()).filter(selector); // .first()
}

// Usage
$('.bg').nearest('.active');

$('.bg').nearest(function() {
   return true || false;
});
```